# Launch a java webstart application from a java application

Tags: java, java-web-start

How can I launch a java webstart application from a java application?

There is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws <URL>");
```

but it seems not the best way to me. I tried using com.sun.javaws.Main but due to lack of documention I don't know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, perhaps this helps:

[Q: How can I start other Web Start apps from my Web Start app?](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#start-app)